# Name that appears in 'From' in a Mailing List

Tags: email, thunderbird, mailing-lists, mailman

I've subscribed a mailing list via mailman.

I've replied to a message using Thunderbird, where I've set a name in the settings of the mail I've used to reply.

In mailman I've filled the field *Your name (optional)*.

My question is: which name will appear in the 'From' section of my email reply? The one that I've set in Thunderbird or the one that I've choose in mailman?

Comment: If you send an e-mail to yourself you can see for yourself what's in the field.

Comment: @AFH that's not going to help in this case. Mailman is the service that they use to send the newsletter, and zar wants to know if a reply will forward his name or that it distributes as MailMan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [MailMan FAQ](https://wiki.list.org/DOC/From%20field%20displayed%20by%20Microsoft%20Outlook), the From field will be altered to the following: 
Mailman on behalf of email address.

Given that you've set your name in Mailman, that is what is being redirected to everyone.

Do note, if you reply to others, you will not get a copy of the mail yourself, but you can refer to the archive to find it there. You can then check what other's see if they get your email.